# Datepicker enable after select symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a 2 fields, symbol and date, if symbol is select after datepicker is enable, without select symbol datepicker is disable.

```html
<script src="{{asset('js/libs/jquery.js')}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>




<div class="form-group col-sm-10">
                {!! Form::label('symbol', 'Symbals:') !!}
                {!! Form::select('symbol_id', [''=>'Choose market']  , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'symbol'])!!}
            </div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-5">
                {!! Form::label('tradedate', 'Traded date:') !!}
                <div class=" input-append date form_datetime" data-date="{{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                    <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" name="tradedate" />
            </div>
```

This script is use datepicker, i use in form of date, time and select month, datepicker javascript available below:
This javascript use timepicker,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        //language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        showMeridian: 1
    });
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0
    });
    $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 1,
        minView: 0,
        maxView: 1,
        forceParse: 0
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear?

Comment: I have a form into 2 field, when symbol not select value then not select date, after select symbol value date field(calendar)is enable or show -@HarishSoni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use jquery
// event is fired when select change
$('#symbol').on('change', function() {
    // this.value - to retrieve the value of selected option

    // do whatever you want. Give 'id' to your datepicker and you can use 'addClass' to disable datepicker depends on plugin you use

    // for example
    if (this.value == 0) {
        $('#datepicker').attr('disabled',true);
    } else {
        $('#datepicker').attr('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

UPDATE

Here I created jsfiddle for you. Look at it. I think you want something like that. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgkoe9n7/11/)

Comment: explain why -1?

Comment: Its code doesn't work for me -@Begmuhammet Kakabayev

Comment: It is not just copy and paste. It won't work. It is impossible to give you copy paste code according to your question (not clear). I was just giving you tips how to do it. Just google it.  @KinnariPrajapati

Comment: yes i change code whenever require but it doesn't work -@Begmuhammet Kakabayev

Comment: what datepicker plugin you use?

Comment: I am using `bootstrap datepicker` @Begmuhammet Kakabayev

Comment: Ok just few minutes

Comment: I updated jsfiddle there was something wrong with jsfiddle update now it is ok. Click it now

Comment: this is not working... `datepicker` allow to pick date...!

Comment: There was something wrong. I updated it. Refresh and click it again. Datepicker is disabled at first. Then when you select something it becomes enabled

Comment: it enable,... nothing is `disable`... well, i have checked ID also which connected with function.

Comment: This is error in `console` : `TypeError: b.val(...) is undefined ` @Begmuhammet Kakabayev